# cv2 and opencv Python troubleshooting install

Tags: python, installation, opencv

I'm totally new to python. Currently I'm trying to install a packaged named cv2/openvc. Having migrated from Rstudio I'm trying to use rodeo in the same way for python. Python definitely seems less user friendly.

When I try to import the package from rodeo and I get following error:

[image]

However, when I run python from the windows cmd line and all works fine, I can even import cv2 and check the version.

[image]

Why is this and how can I fix it?

Comment: you appear to have (at least) 2 separate installs of python. when the rodeo terminal starts. does it tell you what version and/or location of your python executable is?

Comment: No it doesn't state where python is located or version. I have tried to change the python command to ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe to no avail. To be honest I think it's a huge mess now I have so many different versions of packages.

Comment: Could you please post the output of this command: `python -m pip list` ?
It should tell which packages are installed.

Comment: in Rodeo or cmd line?

Comment: in Rodeo (since that is where you would like to work)

Comment: throws up: SyntaxError: invalid syntax (<ipython-input-20-e9362250abe1>, line 1)
  File "<ipython-input-20-e9362250abe1>", line 1
    python -m pip list
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: okay, in that case please use these 2 lines:
`import sys`
`'cv2' in sys.modules`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189345/discussion-between-dasr-and-sameh-yassin).

Answer (score 0):

I can say the best thing you can do is to really know which python installation is being used by Rodeo. However, if you are in hurry you can install cv2 within the python interpreter by this code:

```
import sys
import subprocess
subprocess.call([sys.executable, "-m", "pip", "install", "opencv-python"])
```